# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I receive followng error when the method `GetReponse` was called.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The code:

```
WebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.sample.com.br/sellerItems/123/stock");
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.Headers.Add("appToken", "ABC123456");
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

// Exception thrown here, webRequest is not null
using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse()) 
{
    _httpStatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)webResponse).StatusCode;
}
```

What else can cause that exception and how to investigate it?

I don't understand why the object webRequest (created in the first line) doesn't contain an object instance.

Comment: That error message means exactly what it says; you tried to dereference an object variable that doesn't actually contain an object instance.  Find out what line of code is throwing the exception.

Comment: Can you post the full exception?

Comment: My best guess, looking solely at what you've posted, is that _appToken is null so when GetResponse tries to build the headers, presumably including a call to _appToken.ToString(), it blows up.

Comment: I've updated your post (note that it look like `webRequest` can't be null - please make sure it is indeed true in your case. Also post value of `pUrlCompleta` and `appToken` variables used in the code (if contain sensitive info - just sample value that reproduces the problem would be good).

Comment: Not related to your problem, but it's unlikely that you want to set the `ContentType` here. You only set the `ContentType` when you're doing a POST, so you can tell the server the format of the data that you're posting.

Comment: Is the `NullReferenceException` the immediate exception you get? Then `webRequest` _is null_. Otherwise it'll be wrapped in a `WebException`. So, with @Chris, post the full exception message and stack trace.

Comment: Guys, you all are right. The **webRequest** *is not null*, but the object was created **webResponse** with wrong URL. 

the follow line

    WebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.sample.com.br/sellerItems/123/stock");

does not contains correct URL.

Can I validate **WebRequest.Create()** before submit the **webRequest.GetResponse()**?

Thanks @CodeCaster.

Comment: `WebRequest.Create` will tell you if the URL you pass to it is valid syntax. It can't very well tell you whether the resource actually exists without making a request. *You can't know if your request will fail until you make the request.* That's why you handle `WebException` and such. I think you're asking the wrong question. What error are you getting, and on exactly which line are you getting it? Without a reproducible case, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this the remote name **RequestUri** should be tested before call *webRequest.GetResponse()*. The method *WebRequest.Create()* doesn't check.

Comment: `WebRequest.Create()` will, when passed an invalid URI, [throw an exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc(v=vs.110).aspx): _"Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined"_.

Comment: Nice catch. The OP's exception was thrown by me when I discovered a config issue where an URI was https://www.example.comV3/blahblah . The URI was invalid and your answer clicked to me where the problem was. bravo!